# How to find most frequently used areas of memory?

Tags: c++, memory-management, cpu-cache

I'm looking to profile a large C++ application and determine which pieces of data (or memory regions) are fetched the most. Basically, I want to be able to do something like the processor's MFU cache algorithm for determining what to store in L2/L3 caches. There is surprisingly little to no information online on anybody that has tried to accomplish this.

Edit: Changed MRU to MFU

Edit 2: To clarify, I need the addresses, or the data structures that are pointed to at the addresses.

Comment: What processor?  If x86, have you used VTune already?

Comment: We target both x86 (windows) and powerpc (embedded vxworks). I will take a look at what vTune has to offer.

Comment: Just a side note - there's a difference between most/least *recently* used and most/least *frequently* used

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Leeor, I did mean MFU. I'll edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Pin tool](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/62141/Pin/html/index.html) to log all memory accesses and calculate cache hit/miss.

Comment: I think you have the right answer: [Pin Memory Address Trace](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/62141/Pin/html/index.html#MAddressTrace)
Too bad this isn't packaged in a nice GUI.

Answer (score 1):

valgrind can do this - it will need a plugin , dont know if there is already one.

**EDIT:** it's called `cachegrind`